# What do you call the behavior of a person who stubbornly or sarcastically disbelieves your statements?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

E.g. I’m in an argument with a friend and I make a strong personal point about my self, or intention and she just says “uh huh” or “right” or "whatever".

Me: “I did it because I want better for you”
Her: “yeah, uh huh.”

Basically interjecting disbelief talk backs throughout my argument which is frustrating because I want her to hear and accept what I’m saying but she just pushes away with anger and distrust.

What word would you call that person’s behavior or attitude ?

Comment: Do you have other examples? My first inclination on hearing "I did it for you" as an explanation of behavior that needs explaining is always disbelief, so for your existing example I'd be inclined to call the other person "smart" or "intuitive" or "normal".

Comment: Boring and irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I think that possible words that you are searching for in the first situation are *mocking* or *condescending*.

Comment: @Chappo, here is another person like me.  The question was for a word.  He gives a normal, conversational answer.  Yes, those are words that might work. He assumes people understand how to use the internet or may even know these words already.  Good job tyler1, says me.

Answer (score 1):

The person you described is being [dismissive](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dismissive) with you.

> 1. Serving to dismiss.
> 2. Showing indifference or disregard: a dismissive shrug.

I recommend you avoid this person, if that is possible. If that is not possible, at least limit your interaction with her or him. Sometimes, however, confronting the person in a calm and reasoned way can "clear the air" and perhaps pave the way for a healthier relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly how it is said, the word you are seeking may *contempt*, *scorn*, *disdain*,  or *derision*.

Comment: These options are nouns, but the question is asking for an adjective.

Comment: I know what your saying, but I was responding to their question "What word would you call that person’s behavior or attitude ?"  Since behavior and attitude are nouns, I responded with nouns.  If an adjective was needed, my suggestions could easily be converted to "contemptuous, scornful, disdainful, or derisive".

Answer (score 0):

They are **mirroring**.

The reply shows **they think your statement is insincere**.

**They are *mirroring* you with an equally *insincere* response.**

When mirroring, the intent is to trigger in you the same (dismissed, insulted) reaction they felt hearing your statement.

Alternately they are "calling your bluff" by accepting *superficially*, in word-only, while clearly signaling the opposite. **They are *mirroring* a (false) statement with an equally (false) acceptance.**

Nothing has changed in the positions of the argument. The explanation is being deflected. Communication is breaking down. Change communication tactics or step away.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word **scoffer** may fit.

Comment: This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. Can I suggest you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *scoffer* (linked to the source) and perhaps a sample sentence?

Comment: Yes, I think the official understanding of the purpose of the site does not fit with the way people are using it. Are they aiming for conversational or authoritative?   And why should this site want to be loaded with content copied from other sites?

Comment: I have this problem with every thesaurus question.  Probably I should just not answer.

Comment: The aim is *authoritative*. If you want "conversational", check out our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-and-usage). And given the nature of our site, references from dictionaries, etymologies and similar *reputable* sources would be appropriate, no?

Comment: Ok, then I'll quit

Answer (score 0):

Disinterested?
Unconcerned?
Bored?
AD/HD?

There are many causes of that sort of conduct, from straightforward banal to due to some sort of mental illness.

For example, narcissists are only really interested in themselves and find it difficult to listen to others speaking, when they believe that they should be the only person worth listening to.